# How can I send crash information from my Android app to my server?

Tags: java, android, crash-reports

I am trying to create a structure that sends the errors in the mobile application to my server and shows them in the web interface. But I am new to Android and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/21?sort=created

Answer (score 1):

I would advocate not trying to reinvent the wheel and use something that already exists.

Crashlytics is free and part of the google services.
https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics